# getting input by name is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to assign a value to an input that has a name that is dynamically generated but I can't seem to access the input's value

This is what I'm doing:

```
function calcCorrectedTo(input){
    var name = input.name.split('_');
    var value = input.value;

    var targetName = name[0] + '_' + name[1] + '_4_' + name[3] + '_' + name[4] + name[5];

    var correctedTemperature = calcCorrectedDissipation(10, value);

    var target = $('input[name=' + targetName + ']').val();
}

function calcCorrectedDissipation(temp, value){
    debugger;
    var dissipationFactor = Math.pow(0.5, ((20-temp)/31));
    var correctionCoEff = 1/dissipationFactor;

    return (parseFloat(value) * correctionCoEff);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="icdf_1_3_-1_6077_-1" val="" class="tableInputBox" onblur="calcCorrectedTo(this);">
```

I've stepped through the code and the `targetName` is generated correctly so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong on the line where I'm looking for the input. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Also show us the contents of the `name` array.

Comment: This code works for me when I use static values for targetName, correctedTemperature, and the name attribute of the input itself.

Comment: just updated it. I believe I have tried with and without quotes. I'll try again

Comment: The attribute `val=""` !== value.

Comment: Are you sure "targetName " is what you think it is? `console.log(targetName, $('input[name=' + targetName + ']'));` So what is up with the `_4_` do you actually have an element on the page with that id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is you are generating the name wrong.

```
var targetName1 = "icdf_1_3_-1_6077_-1";
var expected = "icdf_1_4_-1_6077_-1";

var name = targetName1.split('_');
var targetName = name[0] + '_' + name[1] + '_4_' + name[3] + '_' + name[4] + name[5];

console.log(targetName===expected);

console.log(targetName.length, expected.length);
console.log(targetName);
console.log(expected);
```

and the output

```
false
18 19
icdf_1_4_-1_6077-1
icdf_1_4_-1_6077_-1
```

Simple console.log saves the day.

Comment: I honestly didn't even pick that up looking at the picture. I will go slap myself now..

Comment: @john the possibility of having the `targetName` being generated wrong had been brought up a while ago. You should keep a sharp eye out for these kinds of things! :) And always double-check, even if you're sure, haha.

Comment: the reason I posted was because I looked everywhere and still couldn't find an answer so 45 minutes later I decided to post it before I raged. I kept looking at screen shots to see if it's different but didn't spot it. Thanks for clearing my stupid rooky mistake

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your HTML looks like, I think you're missing quotes around your targetName.  Typically, jQuery would access an html input like this

```
$('input[name="somename"]')
```

In your case, you should do this:

```
$('input[name="' + targetName + '"]').val(correctedTemperature );
```

Comment: I just tried this and it still doesn't seem to work. I'm going to have to look around to see if it's not something else that is borked

Comment: Are you sure your generating the right name?  The name is `icdf_1_3_-1_6077_-1`, which has an underscore before the last character set (`-1`), but your generating code doesn't add that. It does this `name[4] + name[5]`.  Would that cause the name to be `icdf_1_3_-1_6077-1`?

Comment: Quotes do not matter unless there is whitespace.

Comment: the -1 is part of the name. I checked the name generated and the field which name I'm trying to generate and it's exactly the same so it is correct. In your case `name[5]` would be the `-1`. Just to clarify, the `_4_` I add manually because the input I  am trying to access will always be on row 4 where as my current input field I am using to generate the target is on row 3. Example: current input is `icdf_1_3_-1_6077_-1`, the target is `icdf_1_4_-1_6077_-1`

Comment: @john clearly the name is not correct. We are noticing that there's a missing underscore that looks like it should be there. Can you confirm this?

Comment: I thought they were since I had two pictures side by side looking at it. I honestly didn't catch it